# GIF not animating on Image Control WPF Application

Tags: vb.net, wpf-controls, gif

I want to overlay a transparent gif over an image control that already has a 'Source'(or the path to the background image) in the xaml file.

my image control looks like this:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CapstoneFinal\CapstoneFinal\Resources\1676035287681.png" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="10"></Image>

        <TextBlock Text="SMCC SCHOOL CAMPUS MAP" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>

        

    </Grid>

    

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Floors:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="20,0,0,0"></Label>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

                <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Padding="5" Margin="10,10,20,10" Content="Fourth Floor" Name="btnFourth" Width="Auto" Click="OpenWindow4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Button>

            <Button Padding="5" Margin="10,10,20,10" Content="Third Floor" Name="btnThird" Width="Auto" Click="OpenWindow3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Button>

            <Button Padding="5" Margin="10,0,20,10" Content="Second Floor" Name="btnSecond" Width="Auto" Click="OpenWindow2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Button>

            <Button Padding="5" Margin="10,0,20,10" Content="Ground Floor" Name="btnGround" Width="Auto" Click="OpenMainWindow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Button>

        </Grid>

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Classrooms:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="20,0,0,0"></Label>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="roomNo" Margin="10,10,20,10" Padding="10">

                

        </ComboBox>

        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="Facilities:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="20,0,0,0"></Label>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <StackPanel x:Name="buttonPanel">


                    <Button Padding="10" Margin="10,10,10,0" Content="Office of the Operation" Name="btnOO" Click="btnOO_Click"></Button>

               

        </ScrollViewer>

        <Image

            Grid.Row="0" 

            Grid.RowSpan="6" 

            Grid.Column="1" 

            Source="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CapstoneFinal\CapstoneFinal\Resources\Ground.png"

            x:Name="myImageControl" Stretch="Uniform">

        </Image>

        </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The function looks like this:

Private Sub LoadPath(ByVal imagepath As String, ByVal pathgif As String)

```
    Dim overlayImage As New Image()

    Dim bitmap As New BitmapImage()

    bitmap.BeginInit()

    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat

    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad

    bitmap.UriSource = New Uri(pathgif, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)

    bitmap.EndInit()

    overlayImage.Source = bitmap

    overlayImage.Width = myImageControl.ActualWidth

    overlayImage.Height = myImageControl.ActualHeight

    myImageControl.OpacityMask = New VisualBrush(overlayImage)

End Sub
```

and the event handler is like this:

Private Sub btnOO_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnOO.Click

```
    LoadPath("C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CapstoneFinal\CapstoneFinal\Resources\Ground.png", "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CapstoneFinal\CapstoneFinal\Resources\officeoperation.gif")

End Sub
```